# I have used this xpath in selenium ,this code works fine printing the text from webtable ,If it is without// in second xpathprinting properly ,

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
List<WebElement> tableelements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@role='rowgroup']//div[@role='row']"));
            System.out.println(tableelements.size());
        for (WebElement eachtablelement1:tableelements)
        {
            List<WebElement> tableelements1=eachtablelement1.findElements(By.xpath("div[@role='gridcell']"));
            //System.out.println();
        
            for (WebElement eachtableelemt: tableelements1)
            {
        
                System.out.print("    "+eachtableelemt.getText());
              // System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Is without // is still a valid xpath  If i include the xpath it prints fromfirst node again

Comment: Take more effort to explain your problem. Also show us the appropriate HTML

Comment: Try using List<WebElement> tableelements1=eachtablelement1.findElements(By.xpath("./div[@role='gridcell']")); is it still working with "./"?

Comment: It is working with "./" also, Thank you for your  brief answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is why **tableelements1** is not working with // in XPath but working without any slash, right?

You are using nested xpath. First you identified the outer element then using that you are identifying the inner element. In your case, the inner element sits right next to the outer element.
While using xpath for inner element, we need to make an important change in xpath - "."
This dot represents "**From current node**". If you didn't mention ".", it will apply the second locator throughout the DOM and look for match. Hence it didn't work in your case too. In short,
"./" ~ "No Slash" ~ "Absolute Xpath".

Since, the second element appears next to first element, it worked without ./ itself. If you try to find some other inner element, it would not have worked. So, prefer using ".//" in the nested xpaths for identifying those further inner elements.

So, all these variations would work in your case:

```
List<WebElement> tableelements1=eachtablelement1.findElements(By.xpath("div[@role='gridcell']"));
```

xpath with ./

```
List<WebElement> tableelements1=eachtablelement1.findElements(By.xpath("./div[@role='gridcell']"));
```

Related articles:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/28333/16916
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3203

Hope I have answered your question.